# Как усовершенствовать поиск на сайте?

Tags: javascript, php, битрикс, google-search

Сайт на Битрикс, но, скорее всего, не суть.

Проблема заключается в том, что если допустить одну ошибку в искомом слове, например, вместо "корвалол" ввести "карвалол", то ничего не найдет.

Нужно сделать более клиентоориентированный поиск, например, как у Гугла ("может вы имели ввиду...").

Первая мысль - создать базу синонимов и при вводе символов джаваскриптом подставлять в выпадающем списке варианты, но, если честно, попахивает большим геморроем.

Какие варианты решения могли бы предложить?

Comment: Точного варианта не подскажу, но возможно стоит поискать в готовых поисковых движках: sphinx , elasticsearch и т.д.

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/432892/
https://ruhighload.com/elastic+%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba+%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85+%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b9

Answer (score 0):

Кодом можно только так: при поиске, если ничего не найдено, для каждого слова в поиске формировать базу всех слов с сайта такой же длинной, потом проходиться по этой базе, сравнивая введенное слово побуквенно с каждым и оставлять только те, в которых различаются не более 20% слова.

Боюсь, это сожрет очень много системного ресурса и поиск будет длительным

Comment: Вы изобрели расстояние Левенштейна, и это уже встроено в поисковых движках

Comment: Описал*) 
Раз битрикс не возвращает своим поиском похожие значения, значит в его движок не встроено.